# How to change specific values in a named range

Tags: excel, vba

This is probably an easy one but I just started using VBA recently. So I defined a single column range of about 10 rows and named it `CB_CL_Values`.

Lets say the range is `{1,2,1,3,2,1,1,1,1,3}` and right now it's set up to change every values of the range to 1.

```
Sub Unit_Options_Reset()
    Range("CB_CL_Values") = 1     
End Sub
```

Lets say I only want to change values `4` to `10` of that range and leave the first `3` as they are. How would I write this?

Comment: `Range("CB_CL_Values").cells(4).Resize(7,1).Value=1` or `Range(Range("CB_CL_Values").cells(4), Range("CB_CL_Values").cells(10))` assuming the activesheet is the one where your named range is sitting.

Comment: + 1 @TimWilliams: I thought of resize too but that wouldn't work for non contiguous cells. for example, 1, 4, 7

Comment: True - but if it's a multi-region range then your Cells() approach also has issues ;-)  If I define a range "tester" as "A1,A3" then cells(2,1) is A2...

Comment: @TimWilliams: multi-region range?

Comment: Multi-area - has non-contiguous cells.  I thought that's what you were referring to in your comment...

Comment: @TimWilliams: No I meant `non-contiguous` cells in one range as in OP's case.

Comment: Still - worth noting for the OP...

Comment: @TimWilliams: Your resize answer still holds good as that is what OP actually requested. You might as well put that as an answer :)

Comment: I used Range("CB_CL_Values").cells(4).Resize(7,1).Value=1 and it works but do you mind elaborating on the code (what resize does). Like I said I'm new to VBA. Thanks!

Comment: @TimWilliams: Stop being lazy and put that as an answer LOL

Comment: @MarcPoirier: Thanks for accepting the answer but wouldn't you want to wait for Tim to post an answer as `.Resize` is the best way to go if you are working with contiguous cells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Range("CB_CL_Values").cells(4).Resize(7,1).Value=1
```

`Range("CB_CL_Values").cells(4)` is the 4th cell in your defined range. By default `Cells(r)` (with one parameter) takes the r'th cell counting across and then down in your range, so if your range was more than one column wide you should use Siddharth's notation (eg) `.Cells(r,1)` (r'th row, 1st column).

Note that if you try to address a cewll which technically isn't in your range e.g.:

```
Range("A1:A10").Cells(20)
```

Excel will not complain that code will reference A20.

`.Resize(7,1)` takes that 4th cell and expands the range to 7 rows in height and one column wide (Resize always expands down and to the right from the starting point)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.Cells` property of the range to address an individual cell. For multiple cells, you can use a loop.

```
Range("CB_CL_Values").Cells(r, 1).Value = "Something"
```

Where `r` is say `3` for third row.